# Bullet Physics ignore collision from bottom

Tags: c#, bullet-physics

I'm currently using BulletSharp a wrapper for Bullet physics.
I'm using Bullet Physics for a 2D project.

Many platform games allow the player to pass through a platform as they jump upwards, and then have it magically become solid so they can stand on it from above.

Can this be done in Bullet Physics? In pre solve or something?

Comment: Did you try to not generate a contact point between the platform and the player if the player's body is goong upwards?

Comment: Did you try searching for [previous Q&A about setting up one-way platforms](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=platform+one+way) or [colliders you can jump through](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=platform+jump+through) and applying the techniques you found through that research to your game? What did you try so far, and where did you run into trouble adapting it to Bullet / your game's context?